# Multiple device inserted notifications

Tags: vb.net, wndproc

Can anyone tell me why when using the following code I receive multiple (three or four device arrival notifications)?

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Const WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219
    Const DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL As Integer = &H8000
    Const DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE As Integer = &H8004

    If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
        If m.WParam.ToInt32() = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL then

          messagebox.show("Device arrived")

        ElseIf m.WParam.ToInt32 = DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE And valid = True Then
           messagebox.show("device left")
        End If
    End If


    MyBase.WndProc(m)

End Sub

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Structure DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
    Public dbcc_size As Integer
    Public dbcc_devicetype As Integer
    Public dbcc_reserved As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst:=16)> _
    Public dbcc_classguid As Byte()

    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=128)> _
    Public dbcc_name As Char()
End Structure


Public Sub RegisterDeviceNotification()
    Dim usb_id As String = "745dd1a8-fca4-4659-9df2-954176705158"
    Dim deviceInterface As New DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE()
    Dim size As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInterface)
    deviceInterface.dbcc_size = size
    deviceInterface.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE
    deviceInterface.dbcc_reserved = 0
    deviceInterface.dbcc_classguid = New Guid(usb_id).ToByteArray
    Dim buffer As IntPtr = Nothing
    buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size)
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(deviceInterface, buffer, True)
    rPS4000 = RegisterDeviceNotification(Me.Handle, buffer, _
                            DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE Or _
                            DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES)

End Sub
```

When a device arrives I am looking to start a thread which will detect which devices are connected to my machine. If the new device is a particular piece of hardware I am interested in (an oscilloscope) then I want to connect to this device using the corresponding driver. The issue I am having is that I get multiple DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL notifications and hence when my device is inserted my software tries to connect with it multiple times - I only want this to happen once. I have a solution to this problem using a timer but I would like to know is there is some way to only receive one DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL notification.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Microsoft's sample application for device notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see if it has the same issue.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I can't find any information on this.

Comment: Just a little tip... Throw a break point in at the ` If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then ` then run the program in Visual Studio. Press F11 to step through and watch what it's doing. Eventually you will see where it get fired again. While this may not directly solve your issue it will prove invaluable.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help you

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    'Used to detected if any of the messages are any of these constants values.
    Private Const WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219
    Private Const DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL As Integer = &H8000
    Private Const DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE As Integer = &H8004
    Private Const DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME As Integer = &H2  '
    '
    'Get the information about the detected volume.
    Private Structure DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
        Dim Dbcv_Size As Integer
        Dim Dbcv_Devicetype As Integer
        Dim Dbcv_Reserved As Integer
        Dim Dbcv_Unitmask As Integer
        Dim Dbcv_Flags As Short
    End Structure

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef M As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        '
        'These are the required subclassing codes for detecting device based removal and arrival.
        '
        If M.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
            Select Case M.WParam
                '
                'Check if a device was added.
                Case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
                    Dim DevType As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(M.LParam, 4)
                    If DevType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then
                        Dim Vol As New DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
                        Vol = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(M.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME))
                        If Vol.Dbcv_Flags = 0 Then
                            For i As Integer = 0 To 20
                                If Math.Pow(2, i) = Vol.Dbcv_Unitmask Then
                                    Dim Usb As String = Chr(65 + i) + ":\"
                                    MsgBox("Looks like a USB device was plugged in!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The drive letter is: " & Usb.ToString)
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                    '
                    'Check if the message was for the removal of a device.
                Case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE
                    Dim DevType As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(M.LParam, 4)
                    If DevType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then
                        Dim Vol As New DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
                        Vol = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(M.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME))
                        If Vol.Dbcv_Flags = 0 Then
                            For i As Integer = 0 To 20
                                If Math.Pow(2, i) = Vol.Dbcv_Unitmask Then
                                    Dim Usb As String = Chr(65 + i) + ":\"
                                    MsgBox("Looks like a volume device was removed!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The drive letter is: " & Usb.ToString)
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
            End Select
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(M)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Original from http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/546243/Howplustoplustellplusaplususerplusplusthatplusaplu